# Build a string from 2 hashes

Tags: perl

I have 2 hashes like the following

```
hash1:
 key      value
 part0     company0
 part1     company1
 part2     company2

hash2:
 key      value
 part0     2B
 part1     4B
 part2     6B
```

What I would like is to build a string using the 2 hashes like this 
      "part0 company0 2B, part1 company1 4B, part2 company2 6B" (without quotes)

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming that you're guaranteed that both hashes have the same keys, you can do something like this:

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %hash1) {
     print "$key $hash1{$key} $hash2{$key}\n";
}
```

If they might have different keys you will need to find a way to get either a list union or intersection, which there's probably a function for in List::Compare.

Comment: Presumably, you intended to write `$key` rather than `%key` in the `print` statement?

Comment: [uniq/distinct](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils#uniq-LIST) from [List::MoreUtils](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils) would work `uniq( keys %hash1, keys %hash2 )`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $answer = "";
my $pad = "";
foreach my $key (sort keys %hash1)
{
    $answer .= "$pad$key $hash1{$key} $hash2{$key}\n";
    $pad = ", ";
}
print "$answer\n";
```

This assumes that `hash2` contains a single, simple entry for each key found in `hash1` (it may contain extra entries, but it may not contain fewer entries).